# Automatic deletion of new mail gmail notification on android when already read online

Tags: notifications, gmail

If I get a new mail in gmail I am happy to see the notification for this.
But if I had read the mail on web gmail on a desktop pc already I don't want to see a notification.

Is there a setting in gmail or an other possibility (app) that the notification is removed as soon as I have clicked on the email in web gmail?

(I searched already similar questions in stack exchange and google. I use kitkat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just recognize it's working what I asked for and only took 5 seconds to synchronize. Maybe functionallity came with a Gmail Update.

Current version:
- Android: 4.4.4
- Gmail App: 5.0.1